# Ruby, MySQL2: check if the result is empty

Tags: mysql, ruby, mysql2

I am using MySQL2 in Ruby to query a database. What is a direct way to check whether the result of a query is empty?
The code looks like:

```
require 'mysql2'
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root")
results = client.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE group='githubbers'")
```

Comment: What's wrong with `results.empty?`

Comment: Are you sure that method exists? I get the following error:
`undefined method "empty" for #<Mysql2::Result:0x9a2afcc`

Comment: my bad, I presumed the result would be an array.  The mysql2 gem documentation [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/0.3.13/Mysql2/Result) indicates there is a `count` method - have you tried this?

Comment: Thanks a lot: `count` works!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Mysql2` documentation is indeed very poor. But by inspecting the type of `results` you will notice that it is a [`Mysql2::Result`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/0.3.13/frames) which contains 3 methods. The one that you are interested in is `count` (or alias `size`) which will return the number of rows of the result.

From here you can easily check if it is `0`:

```
(results.count == 0)
```

Alternatively you could open the `Mysql2::Result` class and add the method `empty?` yourself:

```
class Mysql2::Result
    def empty?
        (count == 0)
    end
end
```

And then you can just do:

```
results.empty?
```

Answer (score 3):

```
0 == results.size
```

will return `true` if `results` is empty. AFAIK there is no direct method (such as `Array#empty?`) , but you could monkey patch it.

Comment: Ruby definitely has `Array#empty?`. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-empty-3F

Comment: Sorry, the sentence was a little ambiguous. I wanted to say: There is no method for `Mysql::Result` that compares to `Array#empty?`. :-)